# Uploading video from phone to Google App Engine Blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, video, mobile, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Python on Google App Engine as the backend for a Desktop/Mobile web app for video sharing. I'm having an issue uploading from an iPhone to the blobstore. Usually the page redirects after the upload URL is created, but this doesn't happen on the phone. Instead the browser navigates to the upload URL, but nothing is uploaded.

I can select a video to upload just fine, and if it's a long video, the phone will take awhile to navigate to the next page which seems to imply that something is being transferred, but nothing ends up in the blobstore.

Videos are uploaded with the following Python code.

```
class UploadPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
  upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/uploadvideo')
  template_values = {
      'upload_url': upload_url,
  }

  template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('upload.html')
  self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
  upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
  video = Videos(content=upload.key())
  video.title = self.request.get('title')
  video.description = self.request.get('description')
  video.ratingDown = 0
  video.ratingUp = 0
  video.creator = users.get_current_user().nickname()
  uniuqeIDFound = False
  newID = random.randint(1000,9999)
  while(uniuqeIDFound == False):
    vids = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                       "FROM Videos ")
    uniuqeIDFound = True                      
  for v in vids:
    if (v.videoID == newID):
      newID = random.randint(1,10000)
      uniuqeIDFound = False
  video.videoID = newID   
  db.put(video)
  self.redirect('/home')
```

The upload page itself looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Upload </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="fill">
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="/home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="/upload" data-toggle="tab">Upload Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout" data-toggle="tab">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 class="addColor">Tribal Knowledge</h2><h3 class="addColor">Upload a Video</h3>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ upload_url }}" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea placeholder="Title..." name="title" cols="50" rows="1" autofocus="autofocus" required></textarea><br>
        <textarea placeholder="Description..." name="description" cols="50" rows="4" autofocus="autofocus"></textarea><br>
        Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Video">
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```